# DENY policy not applied to cognito users with specific role

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

In order to add security checks in my AWS API gateway, I have done the following:

1. I created two groups in my Amazon Cognito user pool:

- manager
- basic_user

2. I created two roles in parallel (manager and basic_user). manager group is mapped to manager role, and basic_user group is mapped to basic_user role.
3. I have created an IAM policy to deny the access to the basic_user users, for a specific endpoint GET crew-manager, and attached this policy to the basic_user role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-2:<my_account_id>:<API_ID>/*/GET/crew-manager"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

4. From Postman, I made a request to GET /crew-manager with the Authorization bearer token of a basic_user. I confirm the only role in this token is basic_user when I decode the token. However, the response is still a 200 instead of an unauthorized-like response.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you say mapping a role to each group you mean through identity pool?

Comment: from Users & Groups / I can add roles to groups in Cognito

Answer (score 1):

Role mappings would only work with the AWS IAM authorizer on your API gateway. If you are using the cognito authorizer you must do the authorization check in your handler or implement your own custom authorizer to return the appropriate policy.

Comment: What you mean is that Authorization must be handled in my backend services ? 

But, let say I have 10 different backend under API gateway, that sounds overkilled

Comment: Then use the custom authorizer or use the AWS IAM authorizer along with identity pool. Groups in cognito don’t translate to IAM groups. However, with cognito identity pool you can grant IAM credentials from a user pool token.

Comment: The Custom Authorizer sounds like the best option. 

So, from this customer authorizer, I would need to:

1. Retrieve the token from the header
2. Check if the token is approved by cognito by making a request to the cognito service
3. Make my personal checks (ex: groups) 

Does it sound like a good approach ?

Comment: Yes you’d verify the token first. Pick a well supported library to do so. Check out https://jwt.io for a good list. Then perform whatever logic you want based off token claims.

Comment: jwt isnt enough as I want to make sure the token is from Cognito right ?

Comment: Yep, you pass the issuer and it will fetch the public key to verify it.